# Props not setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that gets a prop from another parent component. I checked in react developer tools, and the prop is for sure getting passed.

Here is my code:

```
var Post = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { content: this.props.content };
  },
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.state.content, {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
          {this.props.content }
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.rawMarkup() } />
       </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This results in the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` for marked.js. However, when I setInitialState to `return { content: "Blah" };` it works fine. So it looks like the prop is not set there?

But when I do the `{this.props.content}` in the render, it works fine?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @Dylan, I'm using props in setInitialState to synchronize the content field, which it says is an exception to the rule?

Comment: You aren't using `rawMarkup` anywhere in the code snippet you shared. Also it seems to me that `this.props.content` is undefined, while `marked` expects a string. Make sure you are passing the content prop correctly at first render or add a demo.

Comment: @Louy, I took out rawMarkup for the question. `this.props.content` **IS** defined (I have `{this.props.content}` in my render which works fine as shown above)...It's just that it does seem to be undefined when it is called in getInitialState?

Comment: @the_ you don't have to synchronize props. render is called each time when state or props changed

Comment: @the_ why do you need to store it in state though?

Comment: Can you change the line: `var rawMarkup = marked(this.state.content, ...);` to `var rawMarkup = marked(this.state.content || '', ...);`

Comment: @Louy, this fixes it, but I still have the bigger problem of why I can access this.props.content in the render function but not the getInitialState function?

Comment: As I thought. `state.content` is empty at first render. You should listen for changes at `componentWillRecieveProps` and update the state. It's working fine but it's just not updating.

Comment: Why are you storing this in state though? Why can't you just `var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.content, {sanitize: true});` ?

Comment: @Dylan, because unless I'm misreading the docs, anything that responds to user input should be stored in state. I'm taking the props and using it to synchronize/prepopulate the state, and then I have an input that on change will modify that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that your state is out of date. Try adding this:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return { content: this.props.content || '' };
},
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.content !== nextProps.content) {
    this.setState({
      content: nextProps.content || '',
    });
  }
},
```

Read more about components' lifecycle [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

**Edit**: This will solve your problem, but generally using state this way is an anti-pattern (unless content is an input or something, you haven't mentioned that in your question). What you should do instead is create a new component that will only accept `content` prop and render `marked` output. I suggest you use a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components) here.

```
var MarkedContent = (props) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(props.content || '', {sanitize: true})}}></div>
}
```

Drop this component inside your `Post` component like this:

```
var Post = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
          <MarkedContent content={this.props.content} />
       </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Thanks **David Walsh**!

Comment: This should NOT be accepted as the correct answer. As has been pointed out elsewhere, synchronising state with props is an anti-pattern. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @DavidWalsh, If you read the entire page you linked, it mentions: `However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that synchronization's not the goal here:`, where the example shown looks quite a lot like my code. I had left out a significant portion of my code out to simplify the question, but that's on my end. Louy has a great answer.

Comment: The React example pattern is very different to the above. It has a prop called `initialCount` which *initialises* (hence the name) a state variable called `count`. The code above *synchronises* a prop value called `content` with a state value called `content`. It's a flagrant violation of the documented advice.

Comment: @DavidWalsh I know what you mean. You shouldn't use state to store props as they are. However, there's some processing with `marked` and that processed content should be stored in state IMO. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: You're still synchronising state with props, just in a less direct way. State (excepting initial state) should not be derived from props; state should be independent of props. It's much simpler to have `var content = this.processContent(nextProps.content);` in the `render()` function.

Comment: So I guess in case the component had other changeable props and you wanted to avoid re-renders you'd split it into two components?

Comment: @DavidWalsh and @louy, Sorry guys, but I'm pretty sure this is something that **should** be done with state. David, just because variable names are different doesn't mean my example is any different to the above cause. I have an input that uses the props from the parent component to initialize the default state, which I then use an onChange handler to update the state. Using: `var content = this.processContent(nextProps.content)` would take out the ability of me getting an initial state value. If it makes it any an easier, I should have renamed the props: initialContent and then that might

Comment: have cleared some things up. But honestly, I probably just had a confusing question, I'm sorry guys, and thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's not about what you name the variables, although naming is important. If you're using `componentWillReceiveProps` in the manner shown at the beginning of this answer then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think what OP forgot to mention is that `content` will be editable inside that component (a textarea or something). That's a valid use of state IMHO. He mentioned that it will "responds to user input".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to synchronize props with state, even more using props in state is [anti-pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html). `render()` is called each time when props or state changed

> However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that
>   synchronization's not the goal here

```
   var Post = React.createClass({
      rawMarkup: function() {
        var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.content, {sanitize: true});
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
      },

      render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
              {this.props.content }
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.rawMarkup() } />
           </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I was unclear...I have an input which is getting prepopulated with the state, and then changed when the input is changed. I need to set the initial state with the current props

Answer (score 0):

Do all your `Post`'s have `content`?

I guess you are getting the list of posts from somewhere (a database) and for some of them the `content` is `undefined`, hence the:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Probably `this.props.content` has `undefined` as value. Then, `this.state.content` is initialized to `undefined` and when you call `marked(this.state.content, {sanitize: true})` you get this error because you are passing an `undefined` to `marked`.

Comment: I thought this too, but I can put {this.props.content} in my render without any issues

Comment: When `{this.props.content}` is `undefined` it is just ignored in the `render`. So you won't get any error. Just nothing rendered.

Comment: but I do get something rendered?

Comment: I've probably done a bad job of explaining this question, but that's basically been my question all along: I can access `this.props.content` in my render, but when I try `console.log(this.props.content)` inside of my getInitialState function it returns `Undefined`

Comment: Assuming you are not mutating `this.props.content` anywhere... Can you please check if you get the same number of `Undefined` logs if you add a `console.log(this.props.content)` in your `render` too. You shouldn't get any `Undefined` in your `render` then, right?

Comment: Comment your `rawMarkup` method in `getInitialState` first or the error will prevent you seeing the `Undefined` coming from the `render` method.

Comment: Aw, I think I see the problem, though I'm not sure how to fix it: When I do that it console.logs Undefined, then it performs the GET request to get the data then it console.logs the correct data